# Getting an array from the redux store puts it inside another array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch, redux-thunk

So what I am doing is the following:

An action fetches a .json file from a url and dispatches another action. The value for `pilots` is `[Array(278)]`.

```
export const pilotsFetchDataSucces = (pilots) => {
  return {
    type: 'PILOTS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCES',
    pilots
  }
};

export const pilotsFetchData = (url) => (dispatch) => {
  fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {return response.json()})
  .then((pilots) => {
    dispatch(pilotsFetchDataSucces(pilots))
  })
  .catch((e) => {console.log('Error in pilotsFetchData', e)});
};
```

This is the reducer:

```
const pilotsReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'PILOTS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCES':
    console.log('pilotsReducer', action.pilots);
    return [
      ...state,
      action.pilots
    ];

    default:
    return state;
  }
}

export default pilotsReducer;
```

Later in my component I want to access this data. I'm using mapStateToProps.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SinglePilot from './SinglePilot.js';
import { pilotsFetchData } from '../actions/pilots';

class Pilots extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
 this.props.fetchData('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guidokessels/xwing-data/master/data/pilots.js');
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        {this.props.query && <p>You searched for: {this.props.query}</p>}
        {
          //iterate over all objects in this.props.pilots
          this.props.pilots.map( (pilot) => {
            return (
            <SinglePilot
              key={pilot.id}
              name={pilot.name}
           />
          )})
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      pilots: state.pilots // is [[Array(278)]] instead of [Array(278)]
    });

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchData: (url) => dispatch(pilotsFetchData(url))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Pilots);
```

The problem I have is that the value of `state.pilots` is now an array of length 1 and the array that I want (with a length of 278) is inside this array.

I know I could fix this by using `state.pilots[0]`, but I don't like that.
What is causing my initial pilots array to be wrapped inside another array?

Many thanks for any assistance!

Edit: added the code for the reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `pilots` is also an array, you need to spread it as well.

Instead of

```
return [
  ...state,
  action.pilots
]
```

return your new state as

```
return [
  ...state,
  ...action.pilots
]
```

Answer (score 0):

there's an error when using the spread operator , inside the reducer

```
return [
      ...state,
      action.pilots
    ];
```

should be

```
return [
      ...state,
      ...action.pilots
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my state inside reducer

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    employee: [],
    error: ''
}
```

this is the reducer

```
export default function contactData(state = initialState,action)
{
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_EMPLOYEE_SUCCESS :
            console.log(state)
            console.log(action.data)
            return {
                ...state,
                 employee:[...state.employee,...action.data]    //correct way to copy action data to employee array in state
            }

            case FETCH_EMPLOYEE_FAIL :
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading:false,
                    error:action.error
                }

                default:
                    return state
    }
}
```

the data in action.data

```
action.data = {[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist"
    }
  }]}
```

so this action.data is also an array so when i want to put the array type data in action.data to employee array we do like this

```
return {
               ...state,   
                 employee:[...state.employee,...action.data] 
            }
```